# Украинский язык и UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii'

Tags: python, json

Работаю с API last.fm (код прикрепляю ниже), в файле `1.txt` лежат названия известных групп, через обычный `for` я достаю их по очереди, забиваю в ссылку с `API` и получаю нужную информацию в `JSON` объекте.

С русско и англо язычными группами ни каких проблем нет, все работает отлично. А если я ищу группу с на украинском языке, в названии которых присутствует буква `і`, то мой любимый Python выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PY/FILES/ParsLastFm/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    with urlopen(url) as response:
  File "D:\PY\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "D:\PY\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "D:\PY\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "D:\PY\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "D:\PY\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1346, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "D:\PY\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "D:\PY\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "D:\PY\lib\http\client.py", line 1250, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "D:\PY\lib\http\client.py", line 1117, in putrequest
    self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 44-46: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Код:

```
f = open('1.txt')
for line in f:
   line = line.replace('\n', '')
   print("---------------------------------")
   print("Исполнитель: " + line)

   url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&artist=" + line + "&api_key=YOUR_KEY&limit=3&format=json"

   with urlopen(url) as response:
      gettopalbums = json.load(response)
      print(gettopalbums)
```

Как обойти эту проблему?

Comment: версия Python какая?

Comment: О, літера "і" виходить за АSCII. Це не тільки у Пітухоні

Answer (score 1):

Значение URL параметра следует [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), используя [`urllib.parse.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting):

```
from urllib.parse import quote

"...&artist=" + quote(line.strip()) + "&api_key=..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду приложенному у вас 3й питон. Попробуйте параметр artist кодировать перед отправкой.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import json

f = open('1.txt', encoding='utf-8')
for line in f:
    line = line.replace('\n', '')
    print("---------------------------------")
    print("Исполнитель:", line)
    key = "XXX" # Ваш ключ
    artist = urlencode({"artist": line})
    url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&" + artist + "&api_key=" + key +"&limit=3&format=json"
    with urlopen(url) as response:
        gettopalbums = json.load(response)
        print(gettopalbums)
```

Также проверьте, чтобы везде была кодировка UTF-8 (в настройках проекта в IDE и сам файл с данными (группами) был сохранён в нужной кодировке)